# Datatable - Date range filter issue

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs, datatables-1.10

having issues getting the date range function to work correctly. I have 3 date range filters that are partially working. When I start typing the start date, I get errors saying the end time is not defined if I leave the end date empty. Also noticed that ff I type in 2016-04-20 as the start date it shows me 2016-04-17, 2016-04-18 and 2016-04-20.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/bLd00Lh5/10/

Here is my script:

```
$('[id^=min_col_date]').bind('change keyup', function() {
    start_date = $(this).val();
  column_name = $(this).attr("id").slice( -9 );;
  dtTable.draw();   
}); 

$('[id^=max_col_date]').bind('change keyup', function() {
    end_date = $(this).val();
  column_name = $(this).attr("id").slice( -9 );
  dtTable.draw();   
}); 

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

    var filterstart = start_date;
    var filterend = end_date;
    var iStartDateCol = "."+column_name;
    var iEndDateCol = "."+column_name;
    var tabledatestart = aData[iStartDateCol];
    var tabledateend= aData[iEndDateCol];

    if ( filterstart === "" && filterend === "" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isBefore(tabledatestart)) && filterend === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isAfter(tabledatestart)) && filterstart === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((moment(filterstart).isSame(tabledatestart) || moment(filterstart).isBefore(tabledatestart)) && (moment(filterend).isSame(tabledateend) || moment(filterend).isAfter(tabledateend)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
);
```

Would anyone have any idea why it's behaving like this?

Comment: can you please check you are adding all the required jquery libraries

Comment: All the required jquery libraries are loaded, did you notice anything missing?

Comment: Just to be clear it works on jsfiddle but not on your website correct?

Comment: On the jsfiddle it dosent apply the range correctly. If I ask it to filter using 2016-04-20 on the Date1 start field, I am expecting to see all entries after the date I input. But instead it shows me everything. Now when I input a date int he Date1 end field, nothing shows up even if I give it a valid range for example start:  2016-04-17 to 2016-04-20. This returns nothing. Same effects on my website. Let me know if it's not clear :)

Comment: Got it now. thanks

Comment: Not sure if it might help but here is an example of how it's suppose to work. http://www.swartzfager.org/thoughts/demos/dataTablesDateRange/